# How to optimize a matlab function that makes a linear index from a 3D matrix

Tags: matlab, optimization, vectorization, mathematical-optimization

I have written a small piece of code in MATLAB. This is actually a function to make a linear index from a 3D matrix. This is actually part of a bigger project. the problem is the code works but it is not optimized and it is slow. When I run the profiler on MATLAB, 90% of the computation time is consumed by this function. How can I optimize this code?

```
%
A = rand(3,3);
H = 1200;
W = 1500;
S = rand(H,W,3,'uint8')
R = zeros(H,W,3,'uint8');
lIR = zeros(1,H*W*3);
lIC = zeros(1,H*W*3);
count = 0;
for rY = 1:1:H
    for rX = 1:1:W
        [oX,oY] = func1(rX,rY);
        cP = A*[oX; oY; 1];
        cP = cP / cP(3);
        cX = round(cP(1)); cY = round(cP(2));
        if cX < size(S,2) && cX > 1 && cY < size(S,1) && cY > 1
            lIR(count+1:count+3) = sub2ind([size(R) 1],[rY rY rY], [rX rX rX],1:3);
            lIC(count+1:count+3) = sub2ind([size(S) 1],[cY cY cY],[cX cX cX],1:3);
            count = count + 3;
        end
    end
end
%
function [oX,oY] = func1(rX,rY)
C1 = 1000;
C2 = 1200;
C3 = 1500;
C4 = 1700;
oX = C1 + (C3 - C1) * ((rX - 1) / (W - 1));
oY = C2 + (C4 - C2) * ((rY - 1) / (H - 1));
end
```

(Update) Ok, I took out the function from the loop, and now this part is using vector computation, which is way faster

```
[rX,rY] = meshgrid(1:W,1:H);
[oX,oY] = func1(rX,rY);
```

Now the code looks like this:

```
%
A = rand(3,3);
H = 1200;
W = 1500;
S = rand(H,W,3,'uint8')
R = zeros(H,W,3,'uint8');
lIR = zeros(1,H*W*3);
lIC = zeros(1,H*W*3);
count = 0;
[rX,rY] = meshgrid(1:W,1:H);
[oX,oY] = func1(rX,rY);

for j = 1:1:H
    for i = 1:1:W

        cP = A*[oX(i); oY(j); 1];
        cP = cP / cP(3);
        c = round(cP);
        if cp(1) < size(S,2) && cp(1) > 1 && cp(2) < size(S,1) && cp(2) > 1
            lIR(count+1:count+3) = sub2ind([size(R) 1],[rY rY rY], [rX rX rX],1:3);
            lIC(count+1:count+3) = sub2ind([size(S) 1],[cY cY cY],[cX cX cX],1:3);
            count = count + 3;
        end
    end
end
%
function [oX,oY] = func1(rX,rY)
C1 = 1000;
C2 = 1200;
C3 = 1500;
C4 = 1700;
oX = C1 + (C3 - C1) * ((rX - 1) / (W - 1));
oY = C2 + (C4 - C2) * ((rY - 1) / (H - 1));
end
```

Also I tried to make an optimized version of internal function, sub2ind:

```
function ndx = sub2ind_optimized(siz,varargin)
siz = double(siz);
numOfIndInput = nargin-1;
k = [1 siz(1) siz(1)*siz(2)];
ndx = 1;
for i = 1:numOfIndInput
    v = varargin{i};
    ndx = ndx + (v-1)*k(i);
end
```

Still this part of the code is very slow...

Comment: What version of matlab are you using?

Comment: I am using MATLAB 2012b

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just use [sub2ind](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sub2ind.html) - a built in function that convert subscripts to linear indices.

`linearInd = sub2ind(arraySize, dim1Sub, dim2Sub, dim3Sub, ...)` returns the linear index equivalents to the specified subscripts for each dimension of an N-dimensional array of size arraySize. The arraySize input is an n-element vector that specifies the number of dimensions in the array. The dimNSub inputs are positive, whole number scalars or vectors that specify one or more row-column subscripts for the matrix.

For example,

```
A = rand(3, 4, 2);
linearInd = sub2ind(size(A), 2, 1, 2);

linearInd =
14
```

Comment: the first point is the function "func1" is used to process each point and the output is the input for sub2ind. As you can see I am using sub2ind in the code but it is the most time consuming part of the code that should be optimized. So the problem still is not solved.

Comment: Ok, I know understand it is not `sub2ind` that you need to optimize. it is the nested loop. `sub2ind` is already "vectorial" since it can get an input that is more that a single point. Your for loop and if conditions needs to be vectorized.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to optimize this code would be to vectorize it, but I can't seem to figure out how to do that right now, however, I see some thing open to optimization that would probabbly give you a small speedup, first, the line

```
[oX,oY] = func1(rX,rY);
```

could be taken out of the loop and `func1`updated in order to generate two matrices [oX(ry,rj)] and [oY(ry,rj)] and then you would simply access the values instead of calling `func1` again, this would eliminate the time consumed by almost 1.800.000 calls to `func1`, while consuming about 30 MB more memory (I created a 1200x1500 random matrix in matlab, it came up at about 14.4 MB).

In the same vein, the line

```
cX = round(cP(1)); cY = round(cP(2));
```

could simply be

```
c=round(CP(1:2))
```

and then you can raplace `cX` by `c(1)` and `cY` by `c(2)`, eliminating again almost 1.800.000 calls to `round`

Also, I don't see the need to use

```
cX < size(S,2) && cX > 1 && cY < size(S,1) && cY > 1
```

since `size(S,2)=W` and `size(S,1)=H`

Finally, column vectors are a little faster than row vectors due to the way matlab, so changing `lIR` and `lIC` to columns could save you some additional seconds.

I think this could help you improve the spped of the code a little, but it will not give you a speedup nearly as good as vectorizing.

The problem is I can't seem to come up with a way to vectorize correctly the behavior of this block

```
    if cX < size(S,2) && cX > 1 && cY < size(S,1) && cY > 1
        lIR(count+1:count+3) = sub2ind([size(R) 1],[rY rY rY], [rX rX rX],1:3);
        lIC(count+1:count+3) = sub2ind([size(S) 1],[cY cY cY],[cX cX cX],1:3);
        count = count + 3;
    end
```

If I have any new ideas I'll updtate tomorrow, I really need to sleep now.

Cheers

Comment: Thank you buddy, what you mentioned are alright but when I run this code under Profiler in MATLAB, the most time consuming part is 'sub2ind' which is an internal function of MATLAB. Actually I was thinking to replace this function either.

Answer (score 0):

For one you could get rid of func1. You can replace it by

```
for ox = C1:(  (C3-C1)/(W-1) ):C3
```

oy is analogous.

Actually I wonder if it is an error that you increase the counter inside the if condition. Cause then the position in lIR and lIC depend depend on the result. 
Also it is the only value that depends on previous runs through the loop - if you get rid of this dependence the loop can be used with parfor.

Comment: Actually it is not an error to have that if condition, because I want to keep the meaningful part of the result which the size is unknown initially. About parfor; I tried that either but since I have a dual core cpu then no much change.